# Problems with Multiple Applications Setup in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I know this question has been asked numerous times but couldn't find the definitive solution to what I am trying to do.

I am trying to serve multiple apps using single codeigniter 3 installation simultaneously. Specially frontend, backend and other vendor specific interface. This is required because each app has its own login and need to maintain its unique session.

I have gone through codeigniter 3 manual

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/managing_apps.html#running-multiple-applications-with-one-codeigniter-installation

I have setup my app this way as suggeted

```
appfrontend
appbackend
```

As suggested, I have two index files which routes to each application.

```
index.php -> appfrontend
admin.php -> appbackend
```

As suggested in documentation
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file

My ".htaccess" file have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This removes the index.php for frontend and that's fine.

**Question:** How to remove admin.php as well from the URL?

Comment: This is not the way to do this, you should be building a REST API and have your individual front ends interact with it. Also I would stay clear of CI3 its an awful framework for web apps built in the last 5 years

Comment: @MarkTwigg: Thanks for the quick comment. What do you suggest for the best setup in CI3 for this kind of scenario? OFF TOPIC: I have considered Laravel for this project but this has to be hosted on shared hosting as per client's requirement. Laravel seems to be quite complicated for shared hosting as well as issues setting up the project on Windows machine.

Comment: Its not complicated just drag and drop. If you're absolutely stuck with CI3 then I would still separate this out. Create a REST API with CI and then have your separate front end's interact with it. The beauty of this is you can keep adding as many frontends as you want (and not just websites, mobile apps ect) and if you need a change to your business logic you make that change in once place only. This will give you the maximum flexibility going forwards

Comment: I agree with your loose coupling suggestion but do you have any solution for the problem in hand? Thanks!

Comment: @Deepak My Opinion is you to try HMVC Codeigniter which is best for you.